# Is it possible to load TensorFlow model using wamp in a simple html page

Tags: tensorflow, wampserver, tensorflow.js

I am trying to load already trained model into web browser for further use, but I am stuck in the loading step

I am using WAMP and not using node, because the the project is super small and not meant for anything serious.

My question would be, is it even possible to load the module w/o the node ?

I have set up WAMP and folder structure for the mini-project is:

```
.../www/TestProject/
- index.html
- model/
   - model.json
   - group1-shard1of1.bin
```

In the index.html file I tried following ways to load the model
- tf.loadLayersModel('http://...')
- tf.loadLayersModel('localstorage://...')
- tf.loadLayersModel('model/model.json')

I get error messages:

> index.html:13 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Or

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

This is my current script:

```
<script>
    async function model(){
        const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://model/model.json');
    }
    model();
</script>
```

Comment: You changed the name of the weight file, I mean the `.bin` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, TensorFlow.js can work in Node.js OR client side in the web browser like you want. In that case, so long as you host the HTML, CSS, JS, and the model files so they are accessible then it would work fine. However it seems you have changed the file name to modelbin.bin instead of model.bin. My guess is that you are on Windows and have file extensions turned off so it looked like you had the incorrect name but in fact it was there but hidden. I would recommend ensuring this default extension hiding behaviour in Windows is turned off to prevent this in the future. Simply go to Windows control panel (Start -> Control Panel) and then search for "Folder Options". Click on the search result which opens up new window and click on the "view" tab. In that big list of options uncheck the "Hide extensions for known file types" and you should now see the full name of files on your machine. Rename the file to be just model.bin and then it should load correctly.

Comment: Hey, sory for a delayed answer, I re-downloaded the files for the model with original file names (updated the names in the post). I tried the same approaches I did before, but I am still not able to load my model in browser

Comment: How are you hosting the files? Using a web server or opening from hard drive directly  in browser? You will need to host on a webserver which I assume you are doing as you mentioned WAMP stack. In which case how are you generating the model or where getting it from? Can you paste the contents of model.json? Also try using an absolute path to see if that helps eg http://localhost/model/model.json (assuming you are running on port 80)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to load the model since wamp will load all static assets.

However by changing the name of the weight file, it could not be loaded since it is referenced in the topology file `model.json`. The name of the files need to be kept as they were when they were generated or the corresponding names should changed in the `model.json`.